# Perl Net::SMTP::TLS with proxy

Tags: perl, proxy, smtp

Is there any way to connect to an SMTP server through a proxy ?

I am using the Net::SMTP::TLS module to connect:

```
$mailer = new Net::SMTP::TLS(
        'smtp.gmail.com',
        Hello   =>      'smtp.gmail.com',
        Port    =>      587,
        User    =>      $username,
        Password=>      $password);
```

Comment: What kind of proxy is it? Give the software's name and characteristics.